# What is the exact puppet command that vagrant uses for the puppet provisioning?

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I am using vagrant with puppet provisioning. The provisioning setting in my vagrantfile looks like:

```
  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
    puppet.module_path    = "../puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
  end
```

I have another VM which is not managed by vagrant and want to apply the puppet configuration on it. I want to use the exact 'puppet apply' command that is being used by vagrant.

Can someone please tell me the exact 'puppet apply' command being used by vagrant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's open source, you can always look at the source: [plugins/provisioners/puppet/provisioner/puppet.rb](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/plugins/provisioners/puppet/provisioner/puppet.rb). The relevant method is `run_puppet_apply`. And/or you can enable verbose logging on a test provisioning and inspect the log to see the command line.

> I have another VM which is not managed by vagrant and want to apply the puppet configuration on it. I want to use the exact 'puppet apply' command that is being used by vagrant.

That's not going to work. The exact vagrant puppet provisioning command contains references to the temporary attached folders where the vagrant files are.

> Can someone please tell me the exact 'puppet apply' command being used by vagrant?

Nobody will be able to do that because the *exact* command is specific to your environment.

My recommendation is to extract the command applied to one of your existing VMs from the log, and the use this as a starting point to build your own, manual command. The relevant command items are the module paths (which will contain references to temporary shared folders, basically making `../puppet/modules` visible in the VM), your hiera file (which is 'uploaded' into the VM into a temporary file) and the `FACTER` defines, if any.

Comment: I want to apply the configuration using puppet. I could copy all the puppet code (site.pp, hiera files, modules, etc) on the VM and execute 'puppet apply'. For that, I need to know the other parameters that I need to pass to 'puppet apply'. For e.g. I want to know how I could specify hiera details on the command line to 'puppet apply'. I am new to puppet so for me easy thing is to find out the 'puppet apply' command generated by vagrant.

Comment: See in vagrant source how it builds the command line: `options << "--modulepath '#{module_paths.join(module_path_sep)}'"`, `options << "--hiera_config=#{@hiera_config_path}"`, `options << "--manifestdir #{manifests_guest_path}"`, `options << @manifest_file`. So will build up to something like `puppet apply -modulepath /tmp/puppet/modules -hiera_config=/tmp/puppet/hiera.yaml -manifestdir /tmp/puppet/manifests site.pp`

Comment: Based on your input, I executed following command (by setting appropriate param values) and it worked successfully: "puppet apply --modulepath= --hiera_config= --manifestdir= site.pp".

Answer (score 2):

If you need direct answer, the command is

```
sudo puppet apply --hiera_config puppet/hiera.yaml --modulepath=../puppet/modules puppet/manifests/site.pp
```

Normally the current folder (with module and manifest folders and others) will be mounted under /vagrant on guest instance. After `vagrant up` and `vagrant ssh` to that instance, you can cd to folder /vagrant and run above puppet apply command to prove if the command runs fine or not.